# Unable to change directory or file permission [chmod question]

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to change the permission of a file to 444 (read-only).

This directory resides in a NTFS drive. All files in this drive seem to be owned by root.

This is the present permissions for the directory.

`drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul 23 11:41 xxx_directory`

I've tried `sudo bash` and then execute `chmod 444 xxx_directory` to no avail.

The expected outcome was `dr--r--r--` for xxx_directory.

Thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The directories need at least R-X

First, create a mount point in a terminal using 'mkdir'. Then, type the following line to mount the partition with options 'permissions':
`sudo mount /dev/sdXN -t ntfs-3g -o permissions [Mount point]`

Example:

`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 -t ntfs-3g -o permissions /media/Data/`

Then, you will be able to edit the permissions of the files on the NTFS partition with 'chmod' and 'chown' !

Check thia reference [LINUX - MOUNT NTFS PARTITION WITH PERMISSIONS](https://wiki.epfl.ch/icit/kb/linux-mount-ntfs-with-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

You should at least require the `x` permission for directories otherwise you won't be able to `cd` into it.

You can specify the permissions (via fmask and dmask) while mounting the partition ( or in fstab if an entry is there).

An example of an fstab entry :

```
#mounting by UUID
UUID=<partition UUID> /mount/point ntfs-3g user,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0022,fmask=0033
```

This would give all directories in that partition `drwxr-xr-x` parmissions. Any file created will get `.rw-r--r--` permissions. And the ownership would be by the user with uid 1000 so he can change permissions (without sudo)